# Delegate method not updating UI in iPhone

Tags: ios, delegates, nsurlconnection

This is a weird one.  I am using the NSURLConnectionDelegate to retrieve information from a webservice.  In the connectionDidFinishLoading method I send a message to a delegate to update a UITableView and hide a "Loading..." UILabel.  The delegate method gets called and the code to update the table view and hide the label gets called, but the label and table view don't respond.  I have everything connected correctly in IB because I am able to hide/show the label and update the table view when I close/reopen the view.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Relevent Code:

```
// File with NSURLConnection
// .h
@protocol updateTableViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)didFinishLoadingData;
@end

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <updateTableViewDelegate> delegate;

// .m
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
       if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinishLoadingData)]) {
        [delegate didFinishLoadingData];
       }    
}

// connection started with
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];


// File with table view

// conform to <updateTableViewDelegate> in header file
// set the delegate of NSURLConnection object to self in viewDidLoad

-(void)didFinishLoadingData{

    self.viewLoading.hidden = YES;

    // Repopulate array of data for table view
    ....

    [self.tblViewLookup reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Did you start the connection on another thread?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Please post relevant code

Comment: I assume you've put a log in didFinishLoadingData to show that it's called? If you log self.viewLoading and self.tblViewLookup (in didFinishLoadingData), do they give you what you expect?

Comment: @RaúlJuárez code posted

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, when I check if viewLoading is hidden in didFinishLoadingData, it logs correctly

Comment: Then you need to provide  more code, because there's nothing wrong with what you've posted. You should post the table view data source code and how you're hide/showing the label. Also, how do expect the table view to respond? What changes do you expect to see?

Comment: @rdelmar  Let's just focus on the label hiding and the table view should follow suit (I hope).  I'm just using self.viewLoading.hidden=YES; to hide the label. If I were to close the view with this label and open it again, I perform a check if the data has been received. If the data has been received, hide the label.  How I know if the data has been received is I set in NSUSerDefaults, "dataReceieved" = YES.  This setting of NSUSerDefaults is in didFinishLoadingData

Comment: That doesn't really help to diagnose the problem. I need to see the code in its full context. What you say you've done should work, so you must be doing something, somewhere else in the code that's preventing or overriding the simple line, self.viewLoading.hidden = YES. I can't see how that can't be working unless self.viewLoading is nil or it's a pointer to a different label than the one you have on screen.

Comment: @rdelmar Sure, what else would you like to see?  The method where I'm hiding the label is the last method in my code above

Comment: Do you know if your code of `didFinishLoadingData` is executing in the main thread? That is: `[NSThread isMainThread];` is returning `YES`? If this is not the case the put code that access UI in `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ --code here-- });`

Comment: You should post all the code in the controller that contains the code above. You may think what you've posted is the "relevant" code, but clearly there's something else going on that you're not showing.

Comment: @RaúlJuárez [NSThread isMainThread] does return YES.  Hmmm.. so not a threading issue?

Comment: This might help as well.

I have an IBAction to close the view that contains the label and table view.  This IBAction is connected to a button on the view that contains the label and tableview:


This works

    -(IBAction)closeLookupView:(id)sender{
        [self.viewLookup removeFromSuperview];
    }

This doesn't

    -(void)didFinishLoadingData{
    
       [self.viewLookup removeFromSuperview];
    }

Comment: @rdelmar  If it helps, if I put a "refresh" button onto the view and connect it to didFinishLoadingData, then it does refresh the table and remove the label.  But it doesn't seem to do it with the callback from connectoinDidFinishLoading.  The code does get executed from that callback (log statements work and the array of data gets updated).

Comment: Hmmm... that last one is puzzling. It's hard to see how calling it from a button works when calling it from the download class doesn't, unless the download class is not operating on the main thread. Do you start the connection on another thread?

Comment: @ChoppinBroccoli What version of iOS are you using? `NSURLConnectionDelegate` is deprecated and, according to documentation, the method `connectionDidFinishLoading:` is available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3.

Comment: @rdelmar Yup, main thread.  I put a [NSThread isMainThread] right after my initWithRequest and it returns true.

Comment: @RaúlJuárez I'm using iOS6

Comment: If you can post the whole project somewhere, or email it to me, I'll have a look, but I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //Your code to update UI }